# Moving windows server to lamp PHP file stream errors

Tags: php, lamp

I figured this would be an issue eventually and I'm a complete linux noob.  My folder structure is like so:

```
var
+www
++AutoVerify3
+++ajax
+++php
+++results
++++index.php <--The file generating the error
+++users
++++jerred
+++++uploads
++++++combined.xml <--The file I'm trying to open
```

So from the index.php file above, I'm trying to open the combined.xml and I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(AutoVerify3/users/jerred/uploads/Combined.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/AutoVerify3/results/index.php
```

Here is the php code:

```
$xmlFile = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],1,strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/",1)).'users'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.''.$_SESSION['myusername'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_POST['batchFile'];
$xml = file_get_contents($xmlFile);
```

I've tried several different path combinations but my linux knowledge is lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At risk of being too obvious, the file is combined.xml (lowercase) but you're including Combined.xml (capitalised). Sanity check it, and confirm please? :)

Comment: good eye - there is a dependency.  I forgot that linux's FS is case sensitive (told you I was a linux noob).  I disabled the case sensitivity in apache, can I do the same for php as well?

Comment: Not as far as I know, and to fake it is really, really annoying and cumbersome. Ask it as another question, nobody else will see that as a comment here heh :P